# How do you automate a make file?

Tags: makefile

How do you make a makefile go through a list of .cpp files and compile then separately, just like this does statically?

```
test: test.o
        g++ -o test test.o
test.o: test.cc test.hh
        g++ -c test.cc
```

but dynamically from this?

```
SOURCES = main.cpp someClass.cpp otherFile.cpp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OBJECTS = main.o someClass.o otherFile.o

all: $OBJECTS 
%.o: %.cc
   g++ $< -c -o $@
```

If you want to enforce like-named headers for each module, too, then you can:

```
OBJECTS = main.o someClass.o otherFile.o

all: $OBJECTS 
%.o: %.cc %.hh
   g++ $< -c -o $@
```

Answer (score 1):

[automake](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/) makes this even easier:

```
program_SOURCES = main.cpp someClass.cpp otherFile.cpp
```

will build `program` from the listed source files. The only problem is that it works in conjunction with autoconf, which may take some time to set up properly. (At least, I never get it right the first time.)

Comment: As a bonus, you also get correct dependency tracking, GNU standards-compliant Makefiles and `make distcheck`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
SOURCES=$(shell ls *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c %< -o $@
```

This way you don't have to specify any cpp names. Any new source files you add will automatically be picked up. However, this would only work in Unix shells.

Comment: Perfectly valid answer. But purely as a personal preference, I don't like this approach; I realise there is a benefit in not having to keep updating the `makefile` as you add new source files, but I like to be explicit. If I temporarily stick some `.cpp` file in my working directory for whatever reason, I don't want it automatically going into my build: it might not be destined for the build. Of course this is personal preference and also highly context-dependent. :)

Comment: True. I only use this approach because I prefer not to specify every file. I would like to drop in files and know that my makefile will pick it up. Of course, like you said, there is a flip side, but I rarely mix my projects or files, so this has been efficient for me.